# Adding image to word list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I currently have a random list of words that have sounds linked to each of them. I want to link a picture as well but when I try to do it the same way I have for the sounds.

```
<ul style="display:none;" id="wordlist">
  <li data-word="cat" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/porkypig1.wav" data-pic="http://rlv.zcache.com/design_your_own_cartoon_cat_photosculpture-p153525514006078077bfpmd_400.jpg"></li>
  <li data-word="mat" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/daffyduck1.wav"></li>
  <li data-word="dog" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/porkypig1.wav"></li>
  <li data-word="fig" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/porkypig1.wav"></li>
  <li data-word="fog" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/daffyduck1.wav"></li>
  <li data-word="mum" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/daffyduck1.wav"></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the script that pulls it out when my button is clicked...

```
var audio = $("#mysoundclip")[0];
$("button").click(function() {
var noExist = $('td[data-word=' + rndWord + ']').hasClass('wordglow2');
if (noExist) {
    $('#pickNext').click();
} else {
    $("#mysoundclip").attr('src', listOfWords[rndWord]);
    audio.play();
}
});

var pic = $("#mypic")[0];
$("button").click(function() {
var noExist = $('td[data-word=' + rndWord + ']').hasClass('wordglow2');
if (noExist) {
    $('#pickNext').click();
} else {
    $("#mypic").attr('src', listOfWords[rndWord]);
    pic.show();
}
});
```

So the script for the audio works but not for the pic...

```
<img id="mypic" preload="auto">
<audio id="mysoundclip" preload="auto"></audio>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forgetting to add attribute...

```
for(i = 0; i < ul.children.length; ++i){
listOfWords[ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-word")] = ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-audio", "data-pic")
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say that this doesn't work? Your HTML looks valid (you have stored the url of an image in the markup for the LI tag), how are you trying to use the value, is there some JavaScript code that tries to access it? If so please show it to us.

Comment: try an <img> tag instead of <pic>

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code (using FireBug or Chrome Dev Tools)? Put a breakpoint in, and step through it to see where things are going wrong, without seeing the full page that's all I can suggest.